# Many (many!) bookmarks in Firefox make the desktop lock up on hovering "Bookmarks" in firefox. Fixes?

Tags: firefox, freeze, bookmarks

I have several tens of thousands of bookmarks in Firefox. 
Whenever I accidentaly hover over the "Bookmarks" entry of Firefox menu in  global menu, my whole desktop freezes for half a minute.

Now, I know the obvious solution is "less bookmarks". But that is a workaround. I actually consider this a bug, because when an app cannot handle X amount of Things, it should disallow a user to have more then X things :).

But for now, is there a quickfix?

Comment: You could organize your bookmarks in folders and subfolders.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer. Pity, because that requires me to write some parsers for when I export/sync the bookmarks from my online bookmarking tool.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

Optimize *places.sqlite* database. You can do that with BleachBit, [an extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=vacuum&cat=all) or [a sqlite3 script](http://www.webgapps.org/tutorials/firefox/optimization/database-optimization).

If that doesn't help, export your bookmarks to a html file using the **Import and Backup** menu of the *Bookmarks Manager (CTRL+SHIFT+O)*. Then close Firefox, open your profile folder  under ~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxx.default/ or something like that, then rename the file *places.sqlite* to *places.sqlite.bak*. Open Firefox, import your bookmarks from the html file using the **Import and Backup** menu.

Comment: Optimizing helps a little. But does not solve the problem.

Comment: I have added another option to my reply.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. The problem is not that sqlite does not perform well enough or that my database is dirty. The problem is that loading >10.000 bookmarks takes too long; no matter how well my (SSD) system performs nor how clean the database is.